# Using array parameters in Oracle stored procedure sql

Tags: arrays, oracle, parameters, dynamic-sql

We have a PL/SQL procedure containing a basic query returning results from a typical fact table. The dimension values on which WHERE clause in the query is based are passed in as parameters. My questions is: What is the best way to construct the query using those parameters?

Here's some test code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 100000;

-- build table
DROP TABLE T_FACT;
CREATE TABLE T_FACT 
(CUBE_ID NUMBER
,THE_DATE DATE
,DIM1 NUMBER
,DIM2 NUMBER
,DIM3 NUMBER
,DIM4 NUMBER
,DIM5 NUMBER
,VALUE NUMBER)
PARTITION BY LIST (CUBE_ID)
(  
  PARTITION P1 VALUES ('1')
 ,PARTITION P2 VALUES ('2')
 ,PARTITION P3 VALUES ('3')
 ,PARTITION P4 VALUES ('4')
 ,PARTITION P5 VALUES ('5')
 ,PARTITION PDEFAULT VALUES (DEFAULT)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX T_FACT_UK1 ON T_FACT
(CUBE_ID, THE_DATE, DIM1, DIM2, DIM3, DIM4, DIM5)
LOCAL (  
  PARTITION P1
 ,PARTITION P2
 ,PARTITION P3
 ,PARTITION P4
 ,PARTITION P5
 ,PARTITION PDEFAULT
);

ALTER TABLE T_FACT ADD (
  CONSTRAINT T_FACT_UK1
  UNIQUE (CUBE_ID, THE_DATE, DIM1, DIM2, DIM3, DIM4, DIM5)
  USING INDEX LOCAL);

-- add test data
TRUNCATE TABLE T_FACT;
INSERT INTO T_FACT
SELECT MOD(ROWNUM-1,5)+1 AS CUBE_ID
      ,ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE('20010101','YYYYMMDD') , MOD(ROWNUM,48) - 1 ) AS THE_DATE
      ,MOD(TRUNC((DECODE(ROWNUM-1,0,1,ROWNUM-1)) / (5*POWER(30,4))),30)+1 AS DIM1
      ,MOD(TRUNC((DECODE(ROWNUM-1,0,1,ROWNUM-1)) / (5*POWER(30,3))),30)+1 AS DIM2
      ,MOD(TRUNC((DECODE(ROWNUM-1,0,1,ROWNUM-1)) / (5*POWER(30,2))),30)+1 AS DIM3
      ,MOD(TRUNC((DECODE(ROWNUM-1,0,1,ROWNUM-1)) / (5*30)),30)+1 AS DIM4
      ,MOD(TRUNC((DECODE(ROWNUM-1,0,1,ROWNUM-1)) / 5),30)+1 AS DIM5
      ,TRUNC(dbms_random.value(1, 10000)) AS VALUE
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 1000000;

COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DIM_TYPE AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

-- slow procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_SLOW
(
    CubeId_in                   IN  NUMBER,
    DateStart_in                IN  DATE,
    DateEnd_in                  IN  DATE,
    Dim1_in                     IN  DIM_TYPE,
    Dim2_in                     IN  DIM_TYPE,
    Dim3_in                     IN  DIM_TYPE,
    Dim4_in                     IN  DIM_TYPE,
    Dim5_in                     IN  DIM_TYPE,
    Data_out                    OUT DIM_TYPE
)

IS
    Count1     NUMBER := Dim1_in.COUNT;
    Count2     NUMBER := Dim2_in.COUNT;
    Count3     NUMBER := Dim3_in.COUNT;
    Count4     NUMBER := Dim4_in.COUNT;
    Count5     NUMBER := Dim5_in.COUNT;

BEGIN

    SELECT  VALUE
    BULK COLLECT INTO Data_out
    FROM    T_FACT
    WHERE   CUBE_ID = CubeId_in
    AND     (THE_DATE BETWEEN DateStart_in AND DateEnd_in)
    AND     (DIM1 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim1_in )) OR Count1 = 0)
    AND     (DIM2 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim2_in )) OR Count2 = 0)
    AND     (DIM3 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim3_in )) OR Count3 = 0)
    AND     (DIM4 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim4_in )) OR Count4 = 0)
    AND     (DIM5 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim5_in )) OR Count5 = 0);

END P_SLOW;
/

-- fast procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_FAST
(
    CubeId_in                   IN  NUMBER,
    DateStart_in                IN  DATE,
    DateEnd_in                  IN  DATE,
    Dim1_in                     IN  DIM_TYPE,
    Dim2_in                     IN  DIM_TYPE,
    Dim3_in                     IN  DIM_TYPE,
    Dim4_in                     IN  DIM_TYPE,
    Dim5_in                     IN  DIM_TYPE,
    Data_out                    OUT DIM_TYPE
)

IS
    Count1     NUMBER := Dim1_in.COUNT;
    Count2     NUMBER := Dim2_in.COUNT;
    Count3     NUMBER := Dim3_in.COUNT;
    Count4     NUMBER := Dim4_in.COUNT;
    Count5     NUMBER := Dim5_in.COUNT;

BEGIN

    SELECT  VALUE
    BULK COLLECT INTO Data_out
    FROM    T_FACT
    WHERE   CUBE_ID = CubeId_in
    AND     (THE_DATE BETWEEN DateStart_in AND DateEnd_in)
    AND     (DIM1 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim1_in )))
    AND     (DIM2 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim2_in )))
    AND     (DIM3 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim3_in )))
    AND     (DIM4 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim4_in )))
    AND     (DIM5 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim5_in )));

END P_FAST;
/

DECLARE 
    CubeId_in                     NUMBER := 2;
    DateStart_in                  DATE := TO_DATE('20010101','YYYYMMDD');
    DateEnd_in                    DATE := TO_DATE('20030101','YYYYMMDD');
    Dim1_in                       DIM_TYPE := DIM_TYPE(1,2,3,6,15,21,25);
    Dim2_in                       DIM_TYPE := DIM_TYPE(1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10);
    Dim3_in                       DIM_TYPE := DIM_TYPE(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,13,14,15);
    Dim4_in                       DIM_TYPE := DIM_TYPE(1,4,21,22,23,24,29);
    Dim5_in                       DIM_TYPE := DIM_TYPE(2,15,21);
    Data_out                      DIM_TYPE;

    timestart NUMBER;

BEGIN

    timestart:=DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME();

    P_FAST(CubeId_in, DateStart_in, DateEnd_in, Dim1_in, Dim2_in, Dim3_in,
     Dim4_in, Dim5_in, Data_out);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of data values:'||Data_out.COUNT);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Fast proc:' || TO_CHAR(DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME()-timestart));

    timestart:=DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME();

    P_SLOW(CubeId_in, DateStart_in, DateEnd_in, Dim1_in, Dim2_in, Dim3_in,
     Dim4_in, Dim5_in, Data_out);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of data values:'||Data_out.COUNT);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Slow proc:' || TO_CHAR(DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME()-timestart));

END;
/

anonymous block completed
Elapsed: 00:00:00.567
Number of data values:642
Fast proc:22
Number of data values:642
Slow proc:32
```

The reason I have the predicates 'Countx = 0' in procedure P_SLOW is because a requirement of the procedure is that not all dimension values have to be specified. For example, the caller can ask pass in values in Dim1_in but leave the other dimension parameters null, which would mean get all the rows where Dim1 in (x,y) and the other dimension values can be anything.

The problem with the query in P_SLOW, however, is that it is slow - you can see from the excecution time. P_FAST on the other hand is fast, the only difference being it doesn't have the 'OR Countx = 0' predicates in its query. It turns out that adding any 'OR' slows things down.

See the execution plans below:

```
> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
    SELECT  VALUE
    FROM    T_FACT
    WHERE   CUBE_ID = 3
    AND     (THE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('20010101','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20030101','YYYYMMDD'))
    AND     (DIM1 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( DIM_TYPE(1,2,3) )) OR :COUNT1 = 0)
    AND     (DIM2 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( DIM_TYPE(1,2,3) )) OR :COUNT2 = 0)
    AND     (DIM3 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( DIM_TYPE(1,2,3) )) OR :COUNT3 = 0)
    AND     (DIM4 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( DIM_TYPE(1,2,3) )) OR :COUNT4 = 0)
    AND     (DIM5 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( DIM_TYPE(1) )) OR :COUNT5 = 0)
plan FOR succeeded.
> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY)
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1947951911    

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
| Id  | Operation                              | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |            |     1 |   100 |   291   (0)| 00:00:04 |       |       |    
|*  1 |  FILTER                                |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |    
|   2 |   PARTITION LIST SINGLE                |            |  5934 |   579K|   291   (0)| 00:00:04 |   KEY |   KEY |    
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID   | T_FACT     |  5934 |   579K|   291   (0)| 00:00:04 |     3 |     3 |    
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | T_FACT_UK1 |  5934 |       |   290   (0)| 00:00:04 |     3 |     3 |    
|*  5 |   COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|            |       |       |            |          |       |       |    
|*  6 |   COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|            |       |       |            |          |       |       |    
|*  7 |   COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|            |       |       |            |          |       |       |    
|*  8 |   COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|            |       |       |            |          |       |       |    
|*  9 |   COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|            |       |       |            |          |       |       |    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):   
---------------------------------------------------   

   1 - filter((TO_NUMBER(:COUNT1)=0 OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM TABLE() "KOKBF$" WHERE VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B1)) AND             
              (TO_NUMBER(:COUNT2)=0 OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM TABLE() "KOKBF$" WHERE VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B2)) AND             
              (TO_NUMBER(:COUNT3)=0 OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM TABLE() "KOKBF$" WHERE VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B3)) AND             
              (TO_NUMBER(:COUNT4)=0 OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM TABLE() "KOKBF$" WHERE VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B4)) AND             
              (TO_NUMBER(:COUNT5)=0 OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM TABLE() "KOKBF$" WHERE VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B5)))                
   4 - access("CUBE_ID"=3 AND "THE_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2001-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND                  
              "THE_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2003-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))      
   5 - filter(VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B1)      
   6 - filter(VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B1)      
   7 - filter(VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B1)      
   8 - filter(VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B1)      
   9 - filter(VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B1)      

Note     
-----    
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement

 36 rows selected 

> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
    SELECT  VALUE
    FROM    T_FACT
    WHERE   CUBE_ID = 3
    AND     (THE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('20010101','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20030101','YYYYMMDD'))
    AND     (DIM1 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( DIM_TYPE(1,2,3) )))
    AND     (DIM2 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( DIM_TYPE(1,2,3) )))
    AND     (DIM3 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( DIM_TYPE(1,2,3) )))
    AND     (DIM4 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( DIM_TYPE(1,2,3) )))
    AND     (DIM5 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( DIM_TYPE(1) )))
plan FOR succeeded.
> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY)
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Plan hash value: 3872369897    

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                  | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                           |            |     1 |   110 |   440   (1)| 00:00:06 |       |       |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN SEMI                            |            |     1 |   110 |   440   (1)| 00:00:06 |       |       |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN SEMI                           |            |     1 |   108 |   410   (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN SEMI                          |            |     1 |   106 |   381   (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN SEMI                         |            |     1 |   104 |   351   (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI                  |            |    59 |  6018 |   321   (1)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
|   6 |       COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|            |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   7 |       PARTITION LIST SINGLE                |            |  5934 |   579K|   291   (0)| 00:00:04 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   8 |        TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID   | T_FACT     |  5934 |   579K|   291   (0)| 00:00:04 |     3 |     3 |
|*  9 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | T_FACT_UK1 |  5934 |       |   290   (0)| 00:00:04 |     3 |     3 |
|  10 |      COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|  11 |     COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH  |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|  12 |    COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH   |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|  13 |   COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH    |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):   
---------------------------------------------------   

   1 - access("DIM1"=VALUE(KOKBF$))   
   2 - access("DIM2"=VALUE(KOKBF$))   
   3 - access("DIM3"=VALUE(KOKBF$))   
   4 - access("DIM4"=VALUE(KOKBF$))   
   5 - access("DIM5"=VALUE(KOKBF$))   
   9 - access("CUBE_ID"=3 AND "THE_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2001-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND                  
              "THE_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2003-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))      

Note     
-----    
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement

 35 rows selected
```

Now, I can't use an in-list - that is we can't just convert the parameters Dim1_in, etc., into in-lists and use dynamic SQL because we could have thousands of dimension values. I could use temporary tables and copy the arrays into there, but in our real world case, we have 15 dimensions, and performance might suffer. The other option we know of is to build dynamic SQL like:

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM    T_FACT
WHERE   CUBE_ID = 3
AND     (THE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('20010101','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20030101','YYYYMMDD'))
AND     (DIM1 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim1_in )))
AND     (DIM2 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim2_in )))
AND     (1=1 OR DIM3 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim3_in )))
AND     (1=1 OR DIM4 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim4_in )))
AND     (1=1 OR DIM5 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( Dim5_in )))

OPEN mycursor  
FOR mysql  
USING Dim1_in, Dim2_in, Dim3_in, Dim4_in, Dim5_in;
```

when I know that Dim3_in, Dim4_in, Dim5_in are NULL.

Any other options you all can suggest would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you shouldn't do it this way. Relationship between fact table and different dimensions/dimensions’ attributes gives different reports.

1) You do not want to have one master SELECT statement to manage fact table.

2) Collecting into a collection data for one day is easy, for one month may be fine. what about one year or whole history?

The best is to have one SQL statement per one requirement. It is okay to have many SQL statement even if they look similar. Write the results to proper aggregate tables and work from there.

i.e.: it is okay to have a one table with aggregated data and then other aggregates based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Best answer or at least discussion I've found so far is at:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1669972300346534908